# How to Find out running time?

Tags: java

i need to can we implement showing a label with total time taken for the process to execute in JAVA? and how? any code spinet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use timestamps

when your executable starts call:

```
startTime = System.nanoTime();
```

And store the result in a known location.  Then whenever you want to figure out how long you have been running just:

```
totalTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
```

totaltime will hold the total executtion time in nanoseconds.  you could set some sort of timer even to call this and update a label if you want to constantly update it.

Comment: Hey Luke Thks for the info,hey can i use the same method for crawling website? that how many time i used to crawl each site?

Comment: Instead of using those two lines at the start and end of your application, surround your function call to `crawlSite` with the lines.  This assumes you use some sort of loop to perform the crawling and have a "crawlsite"-like function

Comment: ya i am using thread system to crawl the sites, so i will use it in threads and on time of adding data to database use crawlSite function right?

Comment: It depends on how you have it set up.  Basically each time you start crawling a site, set the `startTime` variable and whenever you're done with crawling, calculate and display `totalTime`

Comment: @Alex No problem.  If your problem's solved, be sure to accept one of the answers to your question.  Also, for future reference, it's helpful to use an @ sign before someone's name when replying to them, as it will alert them to a new comment directed at them.  Happy SOing!